# How can I pass parameter

Tags: javascript, raphael

Just for examples

```
machineId = 150018;
paper = raphel('canvas_container', 15, 20);
rect = paper.rect().attr({.....});
rect.node.ondblclick = function() {
  window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + id);     
}
```

Question: How can I pass machineId value to id;

I need the result is to open new window with url http://localhost/graph.php?mach_id=150018;

---

*code from duplicate question*

```
function showUtilization(machineId, rectUtil, txtResult, txtMCName, rectCover) {
    for (i = 0; i < machineId.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/getonemachineinfo.php',
            data: { id: machineId[i] }, 
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                results = data.split(',');

                status = results[0];
                utilize = results[1];

                // Machine Name
                switch (status) {
                    case '0': var colorCode = "#FF0000"; break;
                    case '1': var colorCode = "#33CC33"; break;
                    case '2': var colorCode = "#808080"; break;
                }
                txtMCName[i].attr({ fill: colorCode });

                // utilization
                rectUtil[i].attr({ width: (utilize * conversionFactor())/100 });

                if (utilize <= 30) {
                    var colorAttr = [{ fill: "#FF0000" }];
                } else if ((utilize > 30) && (utilize <= 60)) {
                    var colorAttr = [{ fill: "#FFFF00" }];
                } else if (utilize > 60) {
                    var colorAttr = [{ fill: "#33CC33" }];
                }
                rectUtil[i].attr(colorAttr);

                txtResultAttr = [{ text: utilize + '%'}];
                txtResult[i].attr(txtResultAttr);
                txtResult[i].attr(colorAttr);
                rectCover[i].node.ondblclick = function() {
                    window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + machineId[i]);               
                }
            }
        });
    }
} (2
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided, you should simply reference `machineId` where you want it. But you say that doesn't work, which means that you haven't provided us with anything that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: According to your code, you're passing `2` to the function but then treating it as though you passed an Array `for (i = 0; i < machineId.length; i++) {...machineId[i]...`

Comment: The problem is it redirect to the new page which the undefine machineId

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + machineId);
```

If the (unexplained) problem is that you need to save the value of `machineId` at the time the `ondblclick` handler is *defined* rather than using its value at the time the handler is *executed*, you need a closure:

```
(function (id) {
   rect.node.ondblclick = function() {
     window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + id);     
   }
})(machineId);
```

**UPDATE:** OK, based on the new code you posted I can see I was on the right track with the closure idea above. The problem is that your event handlers try to use the `i` index at some point in the future at which time `i` equals whatever value it had when the loop ended. You need something like this:

```
function showUtilization(machineId, rectUtil, txtResult, txtMCName, rectCover) {
    for (var index = 0; index < machineId.length; index++) {
        (function(i){
           $.ajax({
               // all of your other code here, where anytime it
               // uses i it will be using the parameter of the
               // anonymous function rather than the loop counter
               // (which I've renamed to "index" to avoid confusion
               // with "i")
           });
        })(index);
    }
}
```

I've changed the loop to use a counter called `index`, which is passed in to an anonymous function that is immediately executed. Your existing code, i.e., everything that you have inside the `$.ajax({ });` call goes inside that anonymous function. When your success and ondblclick handlers are executed at some point in the future they will use the `i` from their own closure rather than the loop index.

Comment: the result is localhost/graph.php?mach_id=undefine

Comment: Well there must be more to your code than what you posted so if you want more help you'll have to show (at least) the function that your code is in and how it is called. (You can see all of the other answers agreed with the first part of mine, so I don't think I'm misreading what you already posted. I can't tell if the second part of my answer applies without seeing the context of your sample code.)

Comment: Now It works. Thank you so much. I still don't unstand what you explain. And I'm confused what is the different of i and index.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Feel free to accept my answer (click the tick to the side of the answer; it will turn green), or at least be sure to accept _somebody's_ answer. Sorry, but it's late and I have to go get some sleep so expanding my explanation of closures beyond what I already put in my answer is more than I can manage right now. There are endless other questions on SO with essentially the same problem: just search on something like "javascript loop closure".

Answer (score 0):

`machineId` is scoped globally already, so it will be available for use directly in the `ondblclick` action.  Also, you should add the `var` keyword before the `machineId` declaration.

```
var machineId = 150018;
paper = raphel('canvas_container', 15, 20);
rect = paper.rect().attr({.....});
rect.node.ondblclick = function() {
  window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + machineId);     
}
```

Comment: @Narongdetch Is this code inside another function? Where do you initially define `machineId`?

Comment: @Narongdetch Please post the rest of the relevant code then, where `machineId` is initialized and passed in.

Comment: please see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597860/how-can-i-pass-parameter-2

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the code to

```
machineId = 150018;
paper = raphel('canvas_container', 15, 20);
rect = paper.rect().attr({.....});
rect.node.ondblclick = function() {
  window.open("graph.php?mach_id=" + machineId);     
}
```

That is, instead of `id`, just pass along `machineId`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `id` to `machineId` and your code would work as it is, since you are creating an another function which has access to variables within the scope.

[More explanation on closures and scopes](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: please see the rest of the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597860/how-can-i-pass-parameter-2

Comment: The question you mentioned has been deleted